# Is HSTS (Strict-Transport-Security header) for HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: tls, http, url-redirection, hsts

Is the Strict-Transport-Security header intended for HTTP or HTTPS? What I mean is, do I respond with this header on a HTTP connection which in turn tells the browser to use HTTPS only from that point on? Or, is this header only used on a HTTPS response, and will tell the browser to use HTTPS only from then on?

I'm trying to make my site redirect from HTTP to HTTPS if a client tries to access my site under HTTP. So, I'm interested in whether the strict-transport-security header is used for this purpose, or can be used for this purpose.

Comment: The header should ONLY be sent over HTTPS connections.  This is to prevent issues with broken clients who don't follow the RFC

Comment: "If an HTTP response is received over insecure transport, the UA MUST ignore any present STS header field(s)." http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797

Answer (score 8):

The [HSTS specification draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-websec-strict-transport-sec-14) contains a chapter on the [server processing model](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-websec-strict-transport-sec-14#section-7). It describes the expected behavior for [secure requests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-websec-strict-transport-sec-14#section-7.1):

> When replying to an HTTP request that was conveyed over a secure
> transport, an HSTS Host SHOULD include in its response message an STS
> header field […]

And for [non-secure requests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-websec-strict-transport-sec-14#section-7.2):

> If an HSTS Host receives a HTTP request message over a non-secure
> transport, it SHOULD send a HTTP response message containing a status
> code indicating a permanent redirect […]

This is also reflected in the [various implementation examples of Wikipedia’s *HTTP Strict Transport Security* article](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security#Implementation).